# Android Studio can't run jelly bean on any emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I'm using with android studio and
I can't run jelly bean on any emulator it is stuck on the opening black screen with the "android" title

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using built-in emulator in android studio. Sometimes, that virtual machine is very slow, lag, delay ... I prefer to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) because it provides us an simple interface as well as the stable. [BlueStack](http://www.bluestacks.com/) is also a good option.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it is importent for me to run the emulator on the android studio so how could I fix that?